# Visual Studio Code doesn't update .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-code, csproj

I am having trouble adding new files to a .csproj based project using Visual Studio Code. I can manually edit the .csproj file, but this is somewhat cumbersome. Does VSCode support automatic handling of the .csprojects?

Answer (score 5):

Its bit old question but if someone looks on this, they should not miss this [vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucasazzola.vscode-csproj) to update the .csproj when they add/delete files in the opened project in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks, But This feature is must as inbuilt while working with `.NET` in VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

No, Visual Studio Code isn't that fancy. Use Visual Studio Community or Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop